# If $\ \forall v\in \mathbb C^n \ : \ \langle Sv, Tv\rangle = 0$ then $0$ is the only eigenvalue of $S^*T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to prove the following statement:

> Suppose $S,T$ are two complex $n\times n$ matrices which satisfy: 
>   $$\forall v\in \mathbb C^n \ : \ \langle Sv, Tv\rangle = 0$$
>
> Then, $0$ is the **only** eigenvalue of the matrix $S^*T$ (i.e. $S^*T$
>   isn't invertible).

This is what I've so far:

Let $v=w+u$, then:
 $$\forall v\in \mathbb C^n \ : \ \langle Sv, Tv\rangle = 0 \implies \langle S(w+u), T(w+u)\rangle = 0 \implies \langle Sw+Su, Tw+Tu\rangle = 0 \implies \overbrace {\langle Sw,Tw\rangle}^{0} + \langle Sw,Tu\rangle + \langle Su,Tw\rangle + \overbrace{\langle Su,Tu\rangle}^{0} = 0 \implies \langle Sw,Tu\rangle + \langle Su,Tw\rangle = 0 $$

Am I missing something? I can use the *exchange lemma* in the last step but yet I can't derive the result that $S^*T$ is not invertible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $\lambda\neq 0$ is an eigenvalue of $S^*T$ with an eigenvector $v$. Then
$$
\langle Sv,Tv\rangle=\langle v,S^*Tv\rangle=\langle v,\lambda v\rangle=\bar{\lambda}\langle v,v\rangle\neq 0.
$$

Comment: So simple and yet I was struggling for a long time to solve it. Thank you very much !

Comment: @SyndicatorBBB You are welcome! It happens :)